# Spliting pandas dataframe by date

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataset df with dates:

```
tpep_dropoff_datetime

2020-01-01 00:33:03 (first date)    
2020-02-01 00:16:35 (last date)
```

Desired output should look like this:

```
tpep_dropoff_datetime

2020-01-01
2020-01-02      
2020-01-03
2020-01-04
...
```

Is there a way to split this dataframe to seperate ones by this field. Thanks.

Comment: Can you add a more extensive example of data and desired output?

Comment: What do you mean by "*splitting*"? Your output doesn't looks like a split.

Comment: How does it look like ? :)

Comment: See my answer and let me know if this is what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Difficult to give a complete answer with so few details.

If you really want to split you can use:

```
dfs = [g for _,g in df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df['tpep_dropoff_datetime']).dt.normalize())]
```

Or as a dictionary with the date as key:

```
dfs = {date: g for date, g in df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df['tpep_dropoff_datetime']).dt.normalize().astype(str))}
```

##### as CSV files

```
for date, g in df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df['tpep_dropoff_datetime']).dt.normalize().astype(str)):
    g.to_csv(f'{date}.csv')
```

Comment: Yes, it is what i want. Thank you. Now, maybe there's a way to write these separate groups to separate csv files ? :)

Comment: Yes, see update. Can you please add these details in your original question for clarity?